# How to install Acquai CLI on windows machine

Tags: acquia

I have tried to install Acquia CLI on windows 10, 64 bit version machine but when try to run command `acli auth:login` throwing below error.

Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

```
Warning: mkdir(): Invalid argument in phar://D:/acquia_cloude_ide/acli.phar/vendor/webmozart/json/src/JsonEncoder.php on line 234

In JsonFileStore.php line 325:
  Could not write \/.acquia/cloud_api.conf: failed to open stream: No such fi
  le or directory (2)

In JsonEncoder.php line 283:
  Could not write \/.acquia/cloud_api.conf: failed to open stream: No such fi
  le or directory (2)
```

Comment: Always make sure you're running the latest version with `acli self-update`. Taking it from here, also make sure to follow the docs step by step at https://docs.acquia.com/acquia-cli/install/#installation-procedure (see the Windows tab)

Answer (score 2):

Folks

I found the problem - it was that the PC I am using did not have HOME environment variable set - at the moment I've set both SYSTEM and USER environment variables pointing to my home directory (which is in c:\users\ ) but I'll do some further testing to narrow it down. Suspect setting system environment variable HOME does it for all users, so probably don't need the user env variable.